# Pandas dataframe can't export more than 200 rows to CSV file

Tags: python, pandas, simple-salesforce

I am trying to export the data from salesforce using python and simple salesforce, but when I try to export the data into the CSV File I get only 200 records.
 **Here is my code:**

```
import pandas as pd
from simple_salesforce import Salesforce
import csv
data=Salesforce(password='*********',username='***********',organizationId='***')
results=pd.DataFrame(data.query("SELECT AccountId,
Email_To__c,EM_Escalation_Comment__c,EM_Escalation_status__c,End_Customer__c,Engineering_Action_Required__c,Engineering_Action__c,Engineering_Status__c,EntitlementId,Entitlement_check__c,EPS_Case_Tracking_ID__c,EPS_Reference__c,Error_Code__c,Escalation_Notes__c,Escalation_Status__c,Escalation_Validation__c,Event_ID__c,External_Ticket_Number__c,Handle_Time_Hours__c,Has_Article__c,Has_this_case_reopened__c,Id,Internal_Status__c,In_DBA_H FROM Case")['records'])
df=pd.DataFrame(results) 
df.to_csv('/Users/apple/Desktop/CSV-Py/Case.csv')
```

Comment: Are you sure there are more than 200 rows in `df`? Use `print(len(df))` to check

Comment: are you getting any errors?

Comment: It contains almost 90000 rows

Comment: No errors , everythng works but unable to import the whole data

Comment: Why do you have `df = pd.DataFrame(results)`, when `results` is already a DataFrame? Might not be related to your problem, but anyway, that looks suspicious.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach you are r8 forgot to comment it

Comment: len(df) is 200 for some reason, but when I run the query and don't convert to dataframe and o/p query it says -- OrderedDict([(u'totalSize', 92611),

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the result is extremely large then query will not retrieve all the results. 
Use `query_all` instead.

https://pypi.org/project/simple-salesforce/